# How to check Prettier style with ESLint in Gatsby?

Tags: eslint, gatsby, prettier

I forked React app from [gatsby-starter-default](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default). I want see errors when the project code doesn't match `.prettierrc`. For example, I wish this row with warning because of unconventional for me single quote:

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
```

Please help me.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meninsky-eyvwe)

Answer (score 0):

The prettierrc file in that starter specifies to not use single quotes. Do you use vscode? How is your prettier setup with that? Do you have the prettier extension installed?